# c# Asp.Net 4.0 GridView each row click should redirect user to different page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In database I have a table with two columns Project_Name and Project_Type with sample data as below

```
Project_Name   Project_Type
============   ===========

ProjectA           DotNet

ProjectB            Java

ProjectC            Java

ProjectD            DotNet

ProjectE            Perl
```

Only Project_Name column should be made clickable. Based on the Project_Type  clicking on Project _Name should redirect user to different page and pass Project_Name as parameter  i.e. if project_Type is DotNet it should redirect to “default.aspx?ProjectA” page. If Project_Type is Java it should redirect to “Second.aspx?ProjectB” etc.   Page to re-direct is not stored in the database.

I have couple of questions:-

1)  Is the GridView control in Asp.net is the best option to achieve this? Because I have to     implement paging as well.

2)  If GridView is the right option, in which event and how I can specify the Redirect  page information?

Any references are appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you done any research by yourself..? You want us to do your Home Work? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes GridView control best and You can Use `Row_Bound` event of GridView to Append Your Column Values

Comment: Instead of redirecting user to another page, how about using DetailsView and use modal pop up?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this link,

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-bind-and-pass-query-string-in-HyperLink-in-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx

Particularly look at the ID column in this.